# Meta-regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, xslt

I wrote a file routing utility (.NET) some time ago to examine a file's location and name pattern and move it to some other preconfigured place based on the match.  Fairly simple, straightforward kinda stuff.  I had included the possibility of minor transformations through a series of regular expression search-and-replace actions that could be assigned to the file "route", with the intent of adding header rows, replacing commas with pipes, that sort of thing.

So now I have a new text feed that consists of a file header, a batch header, and a multitude of detail records under the batches.  The file header contains a count of all detail records in the file, and I have been asked to "split" the file in the assigned transformations, essentially producing a file for each batch record.  This is fairly straightforward, as well, but the kicker is, there is an expectation to update the file header for each file to reflect the detail count.

I do not even know if this is possible with pure regular expressions.  Can I count the number of matches of a group in a given text document and replace the count value in the original text, or am I going to have to write a custom transformer for this one file?

If I have to write another transformer, are there suggestions on how to make it generic enough to be reusable?  I'm considering adding an XSLT transformer option, but my understanding of XSLT is not so great.

I've been asked for an example.  Say I have a file like so:

```
FILE001DETAILCOUNT002
BATCH01
DETAIL001FOO
BATCH02
DETAIL001BAR
```

this file will be split and stored in two locations.  The files will look like this:

```
FILE001DETAILCOUNT001
BATCH01
DETAIL001FOO
```

and

```
FILE001DETAILCOUNT001
BATCH01
DETAIL001BAR
```

so the sticker for me is the file header's DETAILCOUNT value.

Comment: Can you add some clear examples.  "I want to transform 'this' into 'that'".  I think the `MatchEvaluator` overloads of `Regex.Replace` might help, but I'm not sure I understand your question yet.

Comment: Under all circumstances, if your input is not XML, stay away from XSLT.

Comment: Regexes can't count by themselves; you need program code to keep track of counters.

Comment: (to me) It's almost impossible to understand the problem here. Counting rows seems like a trivial task - much simpler than splitting the text or reading and writing files (which I suppose you don't do with a regex either `:)`). It isn't clear where is that limit.

Comment: What are the boundaries here? Are you able to pass in a pattern and replacement string and just not edit the existing code?

Comment: That is correct.  Editing the existing code will require resources, testing, quality control, and change control.  If it can't be done, it can't be done, but I'm trying to exhaust all possibilities before suggesting a development effort.

Comment: @Kobi: the regex search and replace functionality is a "poor man's transformation" capability, meant to strip spaces, convert commas to pipes etc.  I am able to split the file with a regex replace expression, although I don't think anyone considers that the ideal solution.  Still, it's good enough, considering the effort implied in more development.  The count thing is the only requirement I cannot currently meet.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: if that is the case, and it's not possible, then that should be the answer.  It looks like that's the case at this point.  If you want the bounty you'll need to respond with an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions by themselves can't count the number of matches they've made (or, better put, they don't expose that to the regex user), so you do need additional program code to keep track of this.

A regex can only capture text that exists somewhere in the source material, it can't generate new text. So unless you can find the number you need explicitly at some point in the source, you're out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it does seem to be the right one.

Answer (score 1):

My program first breaks the text into batches.

I think you'll agree that resequencing the detail number is the trickiest part.  You can do it with a MatchEvaluator delegate.

```
Regex.Replace (
   text, // the text replace part of
   @"(?<=^DETAIL)\d+", // the regex pattern to find.
   m => (detailNum++).ToString ("000"), // replacement (evaluated for each match)
   RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

See how the preceeding code increments `detailNum` at the begining of each batch.

```
  var contents = 
@"FILE001DETAILCOUNT002
BATCH01
DETAIL001FOO
BATCH02
DETAIL001BAR";

  // foreach batch....
  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches (contents, @"BATCH\d+\s+(?:(?!BATCH\d+).*\s*)+"))
  {
     Console.WriteLine ("==============\r\nFile\r\n================");
     int batchNum = 1;
     int detailNum = 1;
     StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder ();
     TextWriter file = new StringWriter (temp);
     // Your file here instead of my stringBuilder/StringWriter

     string batchText = match.Value;
     int count = Regex.Matches (batchText, @"^DETAIL\d+", RegexOptions.Multiline).Count;
     file.WriteLine ("FILE001DETAILCOUNT{0:000}", count);
     string newText = Regex.Replace (batchText, @"(?<=^BATCH)\d+", batchNum.ToString ("000"), RegexOptions.Multiline);
     newText = Regex.Replace (
        newText, 
        @"(?<=^DETAIL)\d+", 
        m => (detailNum++).ToString ("000"), // replacement (evaluated for each match)
        RegexOptions.Multiline);
     file.Write (newText);

     Console.WriteLine (temp.ToString ());
  }
```

prints

```
==============
File
================
FILE001DETAILCOUNT001
BATCH001
DETAIL001FOO

==============
File
================
FILE001DETAILCOUNT001
BATCH001
DETAIL001BAR
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not pure regex; this is c#, which is something I need to pretend I do not have access to.

Comment: So you want a regular expression to be the whole program?
If so look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK
Although my advice would be to write a script that parses and transforms like above. Much easier to maintain!!

Comment: absolutely, no question easier.  This is a square peg in a round hole, but if its possible it's the best of some lousy options.